# How to call GET/POST method programatically using spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I want to call GET/POST method programatically from within the java class using `Spring`. I have done this stuff in Servlet class before but I am not clear how to do this with spring. I went through some related tutorials but I am still not cleared. Can any one please explain how to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: It is simply HTTP based programming, regardless of whether it is using spring or not.

Comment: Previously I did the same stuff in servlet  using HttpURLConnectionRequest class but I am not able to use the same class in spring! How can I create HttpURLConnectionRequest class object in spring?

Comment: show what you have tried and what your errors are.  Personally I use `org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient`

Comment: URL url = new URL(URL);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

I tried above in servlet in Dynamic web project, now I want to give same call using spring

Comment: So, what error are you getting?

Comment: I am not able to import HttpURLConnectionRequest class in my controller. I also tried to update pom.xml, but it didn't worked!

Answer (score 7):

Since you are working on a *Spring* based application, I would suggest using Spring [`RestTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) to request your *GET/POST* endpoints.

The following may be a short snippet of what could be done and you can refer to this *Spring* tutorials ([1](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html),[2](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/4/) and [3](http://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate)) for more details:

```java
public void getOrPostTest() {

  String GET_URL = "http://localhost:8080/somepath";

  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

  Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
  params.put("prop1", "1");
  params.put("prop2", "value");

  String result = restTemplate.getForObject(GET_URL, String.class, params);
}
```

Comment: this getting started guide (https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) is probably a better choice than the tutorial you suggested.

Comment: Yes @BrianClozel you might be right, but I cannot mention a post I dindn't read already. So feel free to update the answer and link a new resource if you that tutorial seems better for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use HttpClient, look this example.

```
      HttpClient httpClient = login(HTTP_SERVER_DOMAIN, "user1@gmail.com", "password");
    GetMethod getAllAdvicesMethod = new GetMethod(URL);
    getAllAdvicesMethod
            .addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    try {
        httpClient.executeMethod(getAllAdvicesMethod);
    } catch (HttpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If you need another method request you can changes GetMethod for

```
        PostMethod postDateMethod = new PostMethod(URL);
```